# How to work with background services Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to create a flutter app that show a notification even when the app is closed.

I managed to find some plugin related to that stuff [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example), but when I tried to replicate the code shown on the example, it shows some error related to the AndroidServiceInstance and setAsBackgroundService() saying that they're not defined. How to fix this ? Is there any better way to achieve what I want ? thanks before.

Here's my current code:

```
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    notificationChannelId, // ID
    'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE', // Title
    description:
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // Description
    importance: Importance.low, // importance must be at low or higher level
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        iOS: IOSInitializationSettings(),
      ),
    );
  }

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,

      notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'AWESOME SERVICE',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
    ),

    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
}

onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
}
```

Comment: `AndroidServiceInstance` and `setAsBackgroundService()` are from te package. if you import the package, they should be defined. try to `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Comment: I've tried to flutter clean and flutter pub get but the package still haven't define AndroidServiceInstance and setAsBackgroundService()..

Maybe I have to downgrade the version ?

Comment: i've post an answer. take a look @Kim

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i just realize after re-create the example app.

you need to import another dependencies:

```
import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';
```

i got same error `AndroidServiceInstance` and `setAsBackgroundService()` is not defined before add the additional package.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
          onSelectNotification: (payload) async =>
              handleLocalNotification(payload, message: message));
      debugPrint('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // titledescription
        importance: Importance.max,
      );

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

RemoteNotification notification = message.notification!;

AndroidNotification android = message.notification!.android!;
```